# Random letters: What is the chance that real words are generated?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

Suppose that we are just typing random letters with our keyboards and we include space bar. We don't distinguish between capital and lowercase letters. If we do this for a long time, how many of the words will be real words? How should one do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: It depends on who types. Monkeys anyone?

Comment: Do humans have a preference for certain letters on the keyboard, in the same way that people **think** they can choose numbers at random?

Comment: `n = 100000;
chars = Union[{" "}, CharacterRange["a", "z"]];
p = DictionaryLookup /@ StringSplit@StringJoin@RandomChoice[chars, n];
(Length@p - Count[p, {}])/Length@p // N`

Comment: @belisariushassettled What exactly does your code return? :)

Comment: Are you counting foreign languages or is it just an English dictionary? Does it matter if words are slightly misspelt (ie they would still be recognisable to a human reader)? Does it count as a "true word" if it isn't separated with spaces from other characters? Do very short words count ("I", "a", "an", "it", etc... they'll clearly be the most likely to come up)?

Comment: I do not think that ´DictionaryLookup" helps here. E.g. for the "German" language the dictionary contains few more than 76000 words. This is by far to few. To cover the "most" words in the German language one would need more than 10 times as much words.

Comment: @mgamer Conceptually the problem is the same. You may just use any word list instead of `DictionaryLookup[ ]`. Define your language as you see fit (plurals, declensions, conjugations, names ...)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Another factor is how you determine how much each key is pressed.  Is each letter and the space bar equally randomly pressed?  Is the space bar pressed 5 times as often since it is 5 times the size?

Answer (score 21):

Just for comparing with Pillsy's answer, let's suppose we generate a uniformly random sequence of a-z and spacebar.

```
SeedRandom[42];
n = 10^7;
chars = Union[{" "}, CharacterRange["a", "z"]]; 
p = DictionaryLookup /@ StringSplit@ StringJoin@ RandomChoice[chars, n]; 

(Length@p - Count[p, {}])/ Length@p // N

(* 0.0071783 *)
```

`2558`out of `356352` are "dictionary words"

And these are the relevant lengths distribution taking or discarding duplicates:

```
Sort@Tally@StringLength@Flatten@p
Sort@Tally@StringLength@Flatten@Union@p

(* {{1, 496}, {2, 1475}, {3, 495}, {4, 83}, {5, 8}, {6, 1}}
   {{1, 1},   {2, 77},   {3, 351}, {4, 82}, {5, 8}, {6, 1}}*)

Select[Flatten@Union@p, StringLength@# > 4 &]
(* {"apnea", "carny", "crony", "hopped", "jacks", "mound", "rhino", "shots", "swags"}*)
```

Comment: And what is the theoretical mean that you should get given your model (and how would you figure it out with Mathematica)?

Answer (score 18):

the probability of a sequence of a given length being a word (as reported by `DictionaryLookup`):

```
 p[n_] := p[n] = (ToLowerCase /@ 
        DictionaryLookup[StringExpression @@ ConstantArray[_, n]] // 
             Union // Length)/26^n // N    (* 27^n if spaces are to be included *)
 Show[{
   ListLogPlot[Table[{n, p[n]}, {n, 3, 20}]],
   LogPlot[ 71625 Exp[-3.6 x  ], {x, 5, 20}]}]
```

[image]

```
numc = 100000;
list = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], numc];
(* for spaces:
list = RandomChoice[Append[CharacterRange["a", "z"], " "], numc]; *)
TableForm[
 res = Table[ {n, 
    Flatten[DictionaryLookup[StringJoin[#],IgnoreCase -> True] & /@ 
       Partition[ list , n, 1]] // Length , numc p[n]} , {n, 3, 20}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None,{"Len", "count", "expected"}}]
Print["total words found: ", res[[All, 2]] // Total, " expected: " , 
  numc Sum[p[n], {n, 3, 20}] ];
```

[image]

> total words found: 5565 expected: 5632.06

Edit re: .. the prediction in consistently high by almost exactly 3/2..
This was because `DictionaryLookup` is case sensitive. `IgnoreCase -> True` fixes it.

I suppose this may be useful to tabulate:

```
 TableForm[ Table[ {k, Sum[p[n], {n, k, 25}]}, {k, 2, 7}] ,
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"min word", "expected words/length"}}]
```

[image]

including spaces (equal proability as a letter) doesn't affect things much..

[image]

and just for fun.. (note `DictionaryLookup` is pretty liberal with what it considers words )

```
numc = 1000;
n = 4
list = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], numc]; words = 
 IntervalUnion @@ 
  Reap[MapIndexed[ 
     If[Length@DictionaryLookup[StringJoin[#], IgnoreCase -> True] == 
        1, Sow[Interval@(Flatten@{#2, #2 + n - 1})]] &, 
     Partition[list, n, 1] ]][[2, 1]];
Row /@ Partition[
   MapIndexed[ 
    If[ IntervalMemberQ[words, First@#2] , Style[ #, Red], #] &  , 
    list], 80] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Let's assume we're generating letters with the same frequency as they appear in the dictionary, in strings with lengths that have the same frequency as the lengths of words in the dictionary. To do this, first we need a list of words:

```
words = DictionaryLookup[];
letters = (Values@# -> Keys@#) &@CharacterCounts[StringJoin[words]];
lengths = (Values@# -> Keys@#) &@Counts[StringLength[words]];
```

Now we need a fast way of testing if something is a word, which we can do using `Dispatch` (which in my testing is about 30 times faster than just using `DictionaryLookup`):

```
Attributes[wordQ] = Listable;
With[{table = Dispatch[Append[Thread[words -> True], _ -> False]]},
  wordQ[s_String] := Replace[s, table]];
```

Then we can see how many words we get if we let our monkeys bang away for a million tries:

```
BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[137];
  trials = 
   Counts[
    wordQ[Table[StringJoin[RandomChoice[letters, RandomChoice[lengths]]],  
      1000000]]]] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.31088, <|False -> 997584, True -> 2416|>} *)

UnitConvert[N[True/(True + False) /. trials], "Percent"]
(* 0.2416% *)
```

So it looks like the answer is about 2.4 in a thousand, using this particular distribution of strings.

Comment: I have this error, what am I doing wrong? http://prntscr.com/9470xq

Comment: @Atvin totally my fault; I copied the wrong thing over. It's fixed now. The problem before was I was using `freqs` instead of letters and never copied over the definition for `letters`.

Answer (score 12):

Of course the answer depends greatly on how you "randomly" choose the letters. Here is a Manipulate that reads in a source text, which is used to define the probability of occurrence of any given letter. It writes a short "poem" based on those probabilities. You can also look at probability "pairs" (how often a is followed by b, how often a is followed by c, etc) or at probability triples (how often ab is followed by a, for instance.) As you increase the length of the correlation, more and more actual words appear.

```
imageNames = 
  ExampleData["Text"][[Flatten[{Range[15], Range[17, 26], 28}]]];
pRange[start_, end_, inc_] := Table[{i}, {i, start, end, inc}];
lenPiece = 850; againOld = False; bookOld = {};
Manipulate[
 If[again != againOld || bookTitle != bookOld, 
  rawString = ExampleData[bookTitle]; againOld = False; again = False;
   bookOld = bookTitle;]; 
 textProc = StringJoin[
   Riffle[ToLowerCase[StringCases[rawString, LetterCharacter ..]], " ", 2]];
 startPos = First[RandomChoice[Drop[StringPosition[
       StringTake[textProc, Round[StringLength[textProc]/2]], " "], 
      3]]] - 1; 
 poem = StringSplit[StringTake[StringJoin[NestList[
      StringJoin[StringTake[#, -(mTerms - 1)], 
        RandomChoice[StringCases[textProc, # ~~ xx_ -> xx]]] &, 
      StringTake[textProc, {startPos, startPos + mTerms - 1}], 
      lenPiece]], mTerms {1, lenPiece, 1}]];
 formatPoem = StringJoin[
   Insert[Insert[poem, "\n", pRange[8, Length[poem], 8]], " ", 
    pRange[1, 1.1 Length[poem], 1]]];
 numLines = StringPosition[formatPoem, "\n"];
 outPoem = StringTake[formatPoem, First[numLines[[Min[Length[numLines], 20]]]]];
 titleLong = 
  StringJoin[Insert[Take[poem, 4], " ", pRange[1, 4, 1]]] ~~ "\n";
 title = StringTake[titleLong, Min[StringLength[titleLong], 30]];
 Graphics[{Text[
    Style[title, Bold, FontSize -> 16], {0, 1}], {Text[
     Style[outPoem, FontSize -> 12, LineSpacing -> {1.1, 0}], {0, 
      0}]}}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
 {{bookTitle, {"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}, "Source Text"}, 
  Thread[imageNames -> imageNames[[All, 2]]]},
 Row[{Control[{{again, False, "New Poem"}, {False, True}}],
   Control[{{mTerms, 3, "      # of Succesive Letters"}, Range[5]}]}]]
```

Here it is, run with Alice in Wonderland as the source text and a correlation length of 1:

[image]

and now with a correlation length of 3

[image]

Comment: +1, but [Lewis Carroll did the same thing a long time ago](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/171647)

Comment: @belisarius -- but did he do it with Mathematica? If not, he would have been closed as off-topic.

Comment: :D As an aside, he tried to get the printer to print it mirrored, but the technical and budgeting difficulties later dissuaded him. He didn't have `Rasterize[ ]`! :)